# in ubuntu the sound card is dummy

Tags: drivers, nvidia, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I have mac mini 2009 and installed ubuntu 20.04 on it sucessfully,but the sound card is dummy i don't get any tone. I searched a lot but i did not find a solution that works for me. I would appreciate if somebody knows it well, to guide me.The sound driver should be realtk hd audio manager. The pc is connected to HDMI that has NVIDIA chip.

```
user@linux:~$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****

sherif@linux:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

I used alsa info and uploaded the information to this [link](http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=4c3f167efaee4692f30f1da0509738555eb41f43), i am adding the alsa-info data also.

```
!!DMI Information
!!---------------

Manufacturer:      Apple Inc.
Product Name:      Macmini3,1
Product Version:   1.0
Firmware Version:      MM31.88Z.00AD.B00.0907171535
System SKU:        System SKU#
Board Vendor:      Apple Inc.
Board Name:        Mac-F22C86C8


!!ACPI Device Status Information
!!---------------

/sys/bus/acpi/devices/APP0001:00/status      11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0103:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0A08:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0E:00/status      11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:00/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:01/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:02/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:03/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:04/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:05/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:06/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:07/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:08/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:09/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:0a/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:0b/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:0c/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:0d/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:0e/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:0f/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:10/status      11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:11/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:12/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:13/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:14/status      11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:15/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:16/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:17/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:18/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:19/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:1a/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:1b/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:1c/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:1d/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:1e/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:1f/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:20/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:21/status      11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:22/status      11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:23/status      11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:24/status      11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:25/status      11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:26/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:27/status      11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:28/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:29/status      11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:2a/status      11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:2b/status      11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:2e/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:32/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:34/status   15


!!Kernel Information
!!------------------

Kernel release:    5.4.0-91-generic
Operating System:  GNU/Linux
Architecture:      x86_64
Processor:         x86_64
SMP Enabled:       Yes


!!ALSA Version
!!------------

Driver version:     k5.4.0-91-generic
Library version:    1.2.2
Utilities version:  1.2.2


!!Loaded ALSA modules
!!-------------------

snd_hda_intel (card 0)


!!Sound Servers on this system
!!----------------------------

Pulseaudio:
      Installed - Yes (/usr/bin/pulseaudio)
      Running - Yes


!!Soundcards recognised by ALSA
!!-----------------------------

 0 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                      HDA NVidia at 0xd3480000 irq 21


!!PCI Soundcards installed in the system
!!--------------------------------------

00:08.0 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 High Definition Audio [10de:0ac0] (rev b1)
    Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation Apple iMac 9,1 [10de:cb79]


!!Modprobe options (Sound related)
!!--------------------------------

snd_pcsp: index=-2
snd_usb_audio: index=-2
snd_atiixp_modem: index=-2
snd_intel8x0m: index=-2
snd_via82xx_modem: index=-2
snd_atiixp_modem: index=-2
snd_intel8x0m: index=-2
snd_via82xx_modem: index=-2
snd_usb_audio: index=-2
snd_usb_caiaq: index=-2
snd_usb_ua101: index=-2
snd_usb_us122l: index=-2
snd_usb_usx2y: index=-2
snd_cmipci: mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
snd_pcsp: index=-2
snd_usb_audio: index=-2


!!Loaded sound module options
!!---------------------------

!!Module: snd_hda_intel
    align_buffer_size : -1
    bdl_pos_adj : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    beep_mode : N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N
    dmic_detect : Y
    enable : Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y
    enable_msi : -1
    id : (null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)
    index : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    jackpoll_ms : 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    model : (null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)
    patch : (null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)
    pm_blacklist : Y
    position_fix : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    power_save : 1
    power_save_controller : Y
    probe_mask : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    probe_only : 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    single_cmd : -1
    snoop : -1


!!Sysfs card info
!!---------------

!!Card: /sys/class/sound/card0
Driver: /sys/bus/pci/drivers/snd_hda_intel
Tree:
    /sys/class/sound/card0
    |-- controlC0
    |   |-- dev
    |   |-- device -> ../../card0
    |   |-- power
    |   |-- subsystem -> ../../../../../../class/sound
    |   `-- uevent
    |-- device -> ../../../0000:00:08.0
    |-- id
    |-- number
    |-- power
    |   |-- async
    |   |-- autosuspend_delay_ms
    |   |-- control
    |   |-- runtime_active_kids
    |   |-- runtime_active_time
    |   |-- runtime_enabled
    |   |-- runtime_status
    |   |-- runtime_suspended_time
    |   `-- runtime_usage
    |-- subsystem -> ../../../../../class/sound
    `-- uevent


!!ALSA Device nodes
!!-----------------

crw-rw----  1 root audio 116,  2 Dec 19 15:55 /dev/snd/controlC0
crw-rw----  1 root audio 116,  1 Dec 19 15:55 /dev/snd/seq
crw-rw----  1 root audio 116, 33 Dec 19 15:55 /dev/snd/timer

/dev/snd/by-path:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  60 Dec 19 15:55 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 120 Dec 19 15:55 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  12 Dec 19 15:55 pci-0000:00:08.0 -> ../controlC0


!!Aplay/Arecord output
!!--------------------

APLAY

**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****

ARECORD

**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****

!!Amixer output
!!-------------

!!-------Mixer controls for card NVidia

Card hw:0 'NVidia'/'HDA NVidia at 0xd3480000 irq 21'
  Mixer name    : ''
  Components    : ''
  Controls      : 0
  Simple ctrls  : 0


!!Alsactl output
!!--------------

--startcollapse--
state.NVidia {
    control {
    }
}
--endcollapse--


!!All Loaded Modules
!!------------------

ahci
applesmc
aufs
autofs4
binfmt_misc
bluetooth
bnep
bpfilter
br_netfilter
bridge
btbcm
btintel
btrtl
btusb
cfg80211
coretemp
crc_itu_t
drm
ecc
ecdh_generic
firewire_core
firewire_ohci
forcedeth
hid
hid_appleir
hid_generic
hid_logitech_dj
hid_logitech_hidpp
i2c_nforce2
input_leds
input_polldev
ip6_tables
ip6t_REJECT
ip6t_rpfilter
ip6table_filter
ip6table_mangle
ip6table_nat
ip6table_raw
ip6table_security
ip_set
ip_tables
ipt_REJECT
iptable_filter
iptable_mangle
iptable_nat
iptable_raw
iptable_security
joydev
kvm
kvm_intel
libahci
libcrc32c
llc
lp
mac_hid
msr
nf_conntrack
nf_conntrack_netlink
nf_defrag_ipv4
nf_defrag_ipv6
nf_nat
nf_reject_ipv4
nf_reject_ipv6
nf_tables
nfnetlink
nft_counter
nvidia
nvidia_uvm
overlay
parport
parport_pc
pata_acpi
ppdev
rfcomm
sch_fq_codel
snd
snd_hda_codec
snd_hda_core
snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep
snd_intel_dspcfg
snd_pcm
snd_rawmidi
snd_seq
snd_seq_device
snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event
snd_timer
soundcore
stp
usbhid
wl
x_tables
xfrm_algo
xfrm_user
xt_MASQUERADE
xt_addrtype
xt_conntrack
xt_tcpudp


!!ALSA/HDA dmesg
!!--------------

[    0.368300] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Dell-Video)
[    0.368300] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)
[    0.368300] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-HPI-Hybrid-Graphics)
--
[   29.006676] PCI Interrupt Link [LAZA] enabled at IRQ 21
[   29.006687] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:08.0: Disabling MSI
[   29.019376] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:08.0: no codecs found!
[   29.040902] applesmc: key=154 fan=1 temp=8 index=8 acc=0 lux=0 kbd=0


!!Packages installed
!!--------------------

ii  alsa-oss                                   1.1.8-1                               amd64        ALSA wrapper for OSS applications
ii  alsa-topology-conf                         1.2.2-1                               all          ALSA topology configuration files
ii  alsa-ucm-conf                              1.2.2-1ubuntu0.11                     all          ALSA Use Case Manager configuration files
ii  alsa-utils                                 1.2.2-1ubuntu2.1                      amd64        Utilities for configuring and using ALSA
```

---

```
sudo lspci -v

00:08.0 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 High Definition Audio (rev b1)
    Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation Apple iMac 9,1
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 21
    Memory at d3480000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [44] Power Management version 2
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

---

```
$ lsmod | grep snd_hda_intel

snd_hda_intel          53248  0
snd_intel_dspcfg       28672  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_codec         135168  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_core           90112  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               106496  3 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
snd                    90112  8 snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
```

---

i found [this article](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/06/fix-no-sound-dummy-output-issue-in.html) but it even does not help. It states there may be a bug.

---

```
sherif@linux:~$ dmesg | grep snd
[   19.429829] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:08.0: dmic_detect option is deprecated, pass snd-intel-dspcfg.dsp_driver=1 option instead
[   19.430433] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:08.0: Disabling MSI
[   19.434742] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:08.0: no codecs found!
[  426.152644] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:08.0: dmic_detect option is deprecated, pass snd-intel-dspcfg.dsp_driver=1 option instead
[  426.152907] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:08.0: Disabling MSI
[  426.157224] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:08.0: no codecs found!
```

for some reason, which i still dont know, it worked after restart, may be the sound card was has a lose contact. It is unclear to me, what made it work, but i tried many things.

Comment: Please confirm: are you hearing sound now?  Also, suggest you perform an upgrade to the latest kernel and drivers. [sudo apt upgrade].

Comment: "dummy" means making no sound?

Comment: yes i am hearing sound now.

Comment: Dummy means i saw a sound card called dummy, that can not be used.